# MS Graph and PHP : Add location that is recognized in Outlook

Tags: php, graph, outlook

we are using the following code in order to add a room (Resource) to the location in Outlook calendar event:

```
 $response = [
            'Subject' => $subject,
            'Body' => [
                'ContentType' => 'HTML',
                'Content' => 'This is event generated by Clebex!'
            ],
            'Start' => [
                'DateTime' => $declaration->datetime_from,
                'TimeZone' => 'UTC'
            ],
            'End' => [
                'DateTime' => $declaration->datetime_to,
                'TimeZone' => 'UTC'
            ],
            'Attendees' => $attendees,
            'Location' => [
               [
                   'displayName' => 'Room 1',
                   'emailAddress' => 'room1@example.com',
                   'locationIdentifier' => [
                       'id' => $organizer,
                       'type' => 'room'
                   ],
               ]
           ],

            'isOnlineMeeting' => true,
            'onlineMeetingProvider' => $meetingProvider
        ];
```

Outlook calendar event is created successfully, but location resource is not recognize as such by Outlook. Instead of that in the location field there is only a string 'Room 1'.

Is there a way to 'force' Outlook to read the information from the location and recognize it as the resource?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, after doing more research: solution is to add the room as attendee, with type 'resource' instead of 'required'.

After this, room is placed in Location field and is recognized as the resource in Outlook.